# Can you rename robots.txt and favicon?

Tags: .htaccess, favicon, robots.txt

I want the following names in my server like this:
(so all server setup and crawler stuff starts with a . to show up first in the list of files, and then my webpage files after in the list of files.)

```
.favicon.ico
.htaccess
.robots.txt
.sitemap.xml
index.php
contact.php
```

Here is the contents of .htaccess :

```
Redirect 301 "/robots.txt" "/.robots.txt"
Redirect 301 "/favicon.ico" "/.favicon.ico"
```

Here is the contents of file ".robots.txt":

```
User-Agent: *
Sitemap: http://example.com/.sitemap.xml
Allow: https://example.com/index.php
Allow: https://example.com/contact.php
```

Is this okay? Everything will run properly? What about the site icon? Is that setup okay? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'd like to have the htm and php files for the actual website together under the crawler and server settings files. Is this ok? Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can rename `robots.txt` and `favicon.ico`, however, you should implement this as an internal rewrite, not an external redirect (which creates an unnecessary additional request). I would also consider using a different character prefix, other than a dot, which generally indicates a "hidden/protected" file (as in `.htaccess`) and may not display by default in FTP-clients. There might already be directives in the server config that prevent access to dot-files. (Perhaps use `@` instead, which I'll use in the following examples.)

You wouldn't normally rename the `robots.txt` (and `favicon.ico`) file for the reason mentioned (to simply affect the ordering of files in the directory). And this could be confusing for other developers. However, "renaming" the `robots.txt` file is quite typical when you need to conditionally serve different `robots.txt` files depending on elements of the request (eg. perhaps you have [multiple domains being served from the same hosting account and you need different `robots.txt` files](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/different-robots-txt-for-two-different-domains-point-to-same-folder) or perhaps you need to [disallow crawling of some domains and allow others](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83922/robots-txt-for-multiple-domains-with-same-website)).

To rewrite the request you need to use mod_rewrite instead. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite from "robots.txt" to "@robots.txt"
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ @favicon.ico [L]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ @robots.txt [L]
```

Which can be "simplified" to a single rule and avoiding repetition:

```
# Rewrite from "robots.txt" to "@robots.txt"
RewriteRule ^(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)$ @$1 [L]
```

`$1` is a backreference to the URL-path that is captured in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `robots.txt` or `favicon.ico`, depending on the request.

To the user-agent (browser / search-engine bot), the "internal rewrite" is *invisible*. It is as if the file is called `robots.txt` and `favicon.ico` respectively.

However, consider blocking direct access to these @-files as well. ie. redirect the request from `@robots.txt` to `robots.txt`. For example, the following would need to go *before* the above rewrite:

```
# Redirect from "@robots.txt" to "robots.txt"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^@(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only direct requests from the client are processed and not internally rewritten requests by the above rewrite.

If you do the same with `sitemap.xml` (ie. all @-files) then the rule can be simplified, as you only need to check for the `@` prefix and don't need to explicitly match the filename. For example:

```
# Redirect and remove the "@" prefix from all requests
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

---

#### Instead of renaming the files, move the other (content) files

Alternatively, instead of renaming these files in the root, why not have all your content (`.php` files) in a subdirectory (eg. `/content`) and rewrite all requests for `.php` files in the root to that subdirectory instead? For example:

```
# Internally rewrite "contact.php" to "/content/contact.php"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.php)$ content/$1 [L]
```

The preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) checks that the target file in the `/content` subdirectory exists before rewriting the request. And then it's a simple task to remove the `.php` extension from your visible URLs. For example, replacing the above rule with:

```
# Internally rewrite "contact" to "/content/contact.php"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ content/$1.php [L]
```

---

#### `robots.txt` format

> ```
> User-Agent: *
> Sitemap: http://example.com/.sitemap.xml
> Allow: https://example.com/index.php
> Allow: https://example.com/contact.php
> ```

The `Allow` directives are not required here (since "allow" is the default). However, the `Allow` (and `Disallow`) directives take a root-relative URl-path, not an absolute URL. ie. It should be `/index.php`, not `https://example.com/index.php` - the later would not do anything since it will never match. (You are also mixing `http` and `https` here.)

Comment: Thank you so much! That works! I went with the @ option and it worked great so far, I will let you know if I have troubles with the favicon.

Comment: Oh, and I actually did know that about the robots, I just forgot when I was making this post. I appreciate that though! That is very nice of you MrWhite! :D

Comment: Thanks! Everything works except 1 minor detail, my icon isn't showing up in search engines... but it never has. I can't figure it out, I am using 256 x 256 ico with all sizes within (192x192 , 128x128, 64x64, 32x32, 16x16, 8x8 and anything else if I missed any too. Thanks again guys!

Comment: @Antarctica-UFO Your favicon not showing in the search results is not related to this issue. There can be many reasons for this, caching, time, file format, etc. This is arguably a Webmasters issue and is better suited to the [Webmasters SE site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), where this has already been answered several times, such as [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/126451/1243), [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/140151/1243) and [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/137519/1243).

Comment: @Antarctica-UFO Note the [Google Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search#guidelines) that states that the size of the favicon should be a multiple of 48px square, so you would seem to be missing some sizes.

Comment: Sorry, yes 48 x 48 is one of the icons included, it has: 16x16 pixels, 32x32 pixels, 48x48 pixels, 64x64 pixels, 128x128 pixels, 256x256 pixels.